# Is it possible to use create a link by entering the URL just once?

Tags: html, css

I am going to place a lot of links on my website and I feel like I am using the `<a href>` like a dummy.

When I am creating links, I want the URL to show the user immediately where the link leads without needing to hover over it first, so I am creating links like this:

```
<a href="https://www.google.com">
    https://www.google.com
</a>
```

But I can't help but feel like I must be missing something. Do I really need to write the URL twice for each link or is there a better way?

Comment: In plain HTML - Yes, you need to specify URL and Text.

Comment: What you have is perfectly valid and expected.  You don't *need* the text within the `<a>` element to be the URL, you are simply *choosing* to use the URL as that text.  (As an aside, users should *never* trust that the URL shown on the page is the URL to which the link directs them and should *always* hover over it and check.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`attr()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr) with pseudo element.

```css
a::before {
  content: attr(href);
}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.google.com"></a>
```